# nginx - Matching location with grouping

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm trying to match nginx regex, however, I'm not able to get it work.

Suppose I have an url, `localhost:8880`, and I want to match it through some location, for example if I typed in `something.com/url`, and it connects to `localhost:8880`, which is easy enough:

```
location /url {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8880/;
    }
```

However, the issue is that I also want the past after `/url` to be included inside the `localhost:8880`, for example, if a user typed in `/url/url_gen/`, then it passes to `localhost:8880/url_gen`, and it should also include any parameters, for example, `?param1=num&param_2=num2`

I tried to come up with something like this:

```
location ~* /url/(\s+)$ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8880/$1;
    }
```

1. The ~* means case insensitive
2. The (\s+)$ means a any non-whitespace characte
3. Then at localhost, I add that group I got from (\s+) to $1.

I've tried searching for nginx regex tutorials, and this is what I was able to come up.

However, it doesn't seem to work, can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse proxing already takes into consideration what comes after specified prefix, as explained in [documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/):

> ```
> location /some/path/ {
>      proxy_pass http://www.example.com/link/;
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Note that in the first example above, the address of the proxied
>   server is followed by a URI, /link/. If the URI is specified along
>   with the address, it replaces the part of the request URI that matches
>   the location parameter. For example, here the request with the
>   /some/path/page.html URI will be proxied to
>   http://www.example.com/link/page.html.